# Efficiently concatenate 1D arrays of variable but known length

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, concatenation

## Problem

I have a `generator` yielding a number of small 1D NumPy arrays of variable but known size. My setup can be mimicked by the following code for the purposes of this question:

```
import numpy as np

n = 1000
sizes = np.random.randint(1,10,n)

def generator():
    for size in sizes:
        yield np.random.random(size)
```

I repeatedly need to concatenate the arrays yielded by this generator into one big 1D array, roughly like this:

```
runs = 1000
output = np.empty(sum(sizes))
further_preparations(sizes)
for _ in range(runs):
    my_concatenate(generator(),sizes,output)
```

I wish to do this as efficiently as possible (without using the C API, Cython, or similar).

## What I considered so far

The following approaches are written the way they are to be ready-to-use with `timeit`, e.g.:

```
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit(with_hstack,number=runs))
```

For reference: Only iterating the generator (`for _ in generator(): pass`) takes 2.6 s. Additionally converting the output to a list (`list(generator())`) takes 2.9 s. In the following, I do not subtract these times:

- **`np.hstack` (5.6 s):**

  ```
  def with_hstack():
      np.hstack(generator())
  ```

  - Pro: Accepts a generator as input.
  - Con: Needs to frequently resize the target array due to not knowing the final size from the beginning.
- **`np.concatenate` (3.1 s):**

  ```
  def with_concatenate():
      np.concatenate(list(generator()),out=output)
  ```

  - Pro: Does not need to allocate the target array.
  - Con: The generator output needs to be converted to a list first, which happens in Python and needs reallocations.
- **Loop with indexing (4.5 s):**

  ```
  def with_loop():
      i = 0
      for array in generator():
          j = i + array.size
          output[i:j] = array
          i = j
  ```

  - Pro: No extended data structures need to be allocated.
  - Con: Python loop.
- **List of array views (3.7 s):**

  ```
  steps = np.hstack((0,np.cumsum(sizes)))
  views = [ output[i:j] for i,j in zip(steps,steps[1:]) ]
  def with_views():
      for view,array in zip(views,generator()):
          np.copyto(view,array)
  ```

  - Pro: No extended data structures need to be allocated.
  - Con: Python loop.

## Question

There is no complete overlap between the drawbacks of the above methods, which suggest that a better solution is possible. For example, the above data suggests that avoiding the list conversion with `concatenate` saves about 0.3 s. Is there such a better solution?

Comment: 'hstack' uses `concatenate`. Look at its code.   I haven't used the `out` of `concatenate` so don't know how much time it saves.

Comment: It may be helpful to include the timings on your sample set, instead of your actual set.  For me it takes about 1.2ms for each method, and they are all pretty much identical performance wise, with hstack being a bit slower.

Comment: @user3483203: Those are the timings on the sample set (for 1000 runs).

Comment: I believe that concatenate without using `out` will be the fastest. Concatenate should allocate an array of the correct size so doing it yourself is just another step of having to jump from Python to C to Python before assignment instead of allowing concatenate to simply do it all in C. @hpaulj is correct as hstack does use concatenate plus a bit more (i.e. overhead).

Comment: It depends on the array size and how many arrays you wan't to concatenate (Concatenation -> allocate a new array (oldsize+sizeToAdd), copying all the data to the new array and this repeadetly). For larger problems I would recommend to append the arrays to a list (only some Pointer arithmetic necessary and create at the end a new array where you copy all your data into it. Is your benchmark really compareable to your real code?

Comment: Testing various options, I'd say the simplest is best - `np.concatenate(list(generator()))`.  The biggest time consumer in this expression is just running `generator()` to its `StopIteration`.  Accumulating the values in a list, and concatenating that list are comparatively fast.  I do my `timeit` tests in `ipython` where it is easy to test bits and pieces of the calculations.

Comment: @max9111: *For larger problems I would recommend to append the arrays to a list (only some Pointer arithmetic necessary and create at the end a new array where you copy all your data into it.* – I am not exactly sure what you are suggesting, but since Python lists are realised as arrays, this would probably lead to resizing issues. Anyway, this sounds like it should be an answer.

Comment: @hpaulj: That also sounds like it should be an answer, and not a comment.